# How can I enable javascript in the integrated Epiphany web browser?

Tags: web-browsers, bugs, javascript

Javascript worked just fine on my Raspberry Pi 2, but after the browser silently crashed, it no longer works. I can still browse, but javascript no longer works.

I tried rebooting, no effect.

I updated everything, then uninstalled and re-installed the browser, but javascript still doesn't work.

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get upgrade

sudo apt-get remove epiphany-browser

sudo apt-get install epiphany-browser
```

I can't find anything in the limited settings dialog of the browser regarding javascript.

(sorry for the not so well-descriptive tag, but as I'm typing on my pi now, I can't see the tag autocomplete, so I guessed a tag to be able to submit the question)